# How To find the nearest distance along a polyline Mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-spatial

I am building a ride sharing application.

The application has a feature for searching drivers.

The drivers (employees in a work hub) can choose a route to their destination from the app.

The passengers, who also belong to the work hub, and are within the route, can join their ride.

This is accomplished by search functionality after user enter their destination in the app.

Here is the table structure of rides

```
id  driver_id path
 1     1       BLOB
```

Here `driver id` is the id of driver and `path` is the line string from drivers source to destination.For the sake of simplicity I won't include other fields

My task is to find all the drivers who passes through my location with 85% or above ride match

After having a look at  `Mysql spatial Types` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/spatial-types.html I wrote a query of my own which looks partially ok, Please see the query below

```
set @g1=ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(10.013059 76.363075,10.0168011
 76.34592529999999,10.0161831
 76.34368020000001,10.0118 76.3218,9.99848 76.311936,9.9771685 76.2773228
)');
SET @g2 = ST_GeomFromText('Point(10.0141713 76.33320359999999
)');
 
 SELECT MBRCovers(@g1,@g2)
```

works fine `Point(10.0141713 76.33320359999999)` is between `Point(10.013059 76.363075) and point(9.9771685 76.2773228)`

but this won't work

```
 set @g1=ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(10.013059 76.363075,10.0168011
 76.34592529999999,10.0161831
 76.34368020000001,10.0118 76.3218,9.99848 76.311936,9.9771685 76.2773228
)');
SET @g2 = ST_GeomFromText('Point(10.0185876 76.3439941
)');
 
 SELECT MBRCovers(@g1,@g2)
```

`Point(10.0185876 76.3439941)` is also between `Point(10.013059 76.363075) and point(9.9771685 76.2773228)`,

I think I need to add some covering distance for the above `point` to return true which I am not aware about.

I am expecting  above 85 % of ride match.

What I mean by that is user is not necessary belongs to the line string the driver chosen, small tolerances are allowed.

I am using mysql version 8.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> set @g1=ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(10.013059  76.363075,
>                                     10.0168011 76.34592529999999,
>                                     10.0161831 76.34368020000001,
>                                     10.0118    76.3218,
>                                     9.99848    76.311936,
>                                     9.9771685  76.2773228)', 4326);
> SET @g2 = ST_GeomFromText('Point(10.0141713 76.33320359999999)', 4326);
> SELECT ST_Distance(@g1, @g2, 'metre');
> ```
>
> ```
> | ST_Distance(@g1, @g2, 'metre') |
> | -----------------------------: |
> |              9.402168864952756 |
> ```

> ```
> set @g1=ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(10.013059  76.363075,
>                                     10.0168011 76.34592529999999,
>                                     10.0161831 76.34368020000001,
>                                     10.0118    76.3218,
>                                     9.99848    76.311936,
>                                     9.9771685  76.2773228)', 4326);
> SET @g2 = ST_GeomFromText('Point(10.0185876 76.3439941)', 4326);
> SELECT ST_Distance(@g1, @g2, 'metre');
> ```
>
> ```
> | ST_Distance(@g1, @g2, 'metre') |
> | -----------------------------: |
> |              247.0472114965831 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=552bd07d48a32ac4e5c0bdf6f1931c54)*

Comment: Thanks for answering, Just a question i am wondering How can this query make sure that the passenger are within drivers route?

Comment: also i got this error `15:57:48 SELECT ST_Distance(@g1, @g2, 'metre') LIMIT 0, 1000 Error Code: 3618. st_distance(LINESTRING, POINT) has not been implemented for geographic spatial reference systems. 0.000 sec
`in local machine which works fine in fiddle

Comment: @soju *How can this query make sure that the passenger are within drivers route?* The probability that the point posesses on a line strictly is close to zero. You must check that the distance between the point and the linestring is below some pre-defined accuracy. *also i got this error* What is precise version of your server? try to use not POINT but LINESTRING for your point. I.e. not `POINT(x y)` but `LINESTRING(x y, x y)`.

Comment: Version is  8.0.16

Comment: @soju As the documentation claims, "Prior to MySQL 8.0.18, the only permitted geographic argument types are Point and Point, or Point and MultiPoint (in any argument order)." Upgrade your server if possible.

Comment: thank you. can we calculate the distance for the previous version without st_distance?

Comment: @soju Try to apply `ST_Distance_Sphere()`... its accuracy is ~5% with your data.

Comment: seems like i need an upgrade,These functions are not working for me. i will upgrade to 8.0.18. can you please explain me why `MBRCovers` won't work to find passenger are within drivers route.i didn't get it right from mysql doc

Comment: @soju Route is a line, not a stripe. Its width is zero.